# gerrit replication

Tags: replication, gerrit

What triggers replication in gerrit? I push a change up for review, review and hit "Submit and Publish", but replication does not take place? I even set the replication delay to 0. If I reload the replication plugin then replication takes place or if I restart gerrit. So not really sure what is supposed to trigger it. Any ideas?

Comment: You should say which version of gerrit you're using, because setup for replication changed in 2.5.

Comment: Good point, v2.5. It looks like my problem is resolved with a restart of gerrit. Replication seems to be progressing as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger replication manually like this: ssh -p 29419 user@localhost replication start --all